# Create JavaFx Combobox and hide the dropdown arrow without using css

Tags: javafx-8

How to create a **JavaFx ComboBox** and **hide the dropdown arrow**, it should show the list only when mouse is clicked on combobox. Note- we must **not use CSS**

Comment: CSS is the way to do this. Why must you not use it?

Comment: I was asked this question in an interview. So is CSS only the way to do? or do we have any other way around?

Comment: You could do a lookup: e.g. `comboBox.lookup(".arrow-button")` and manipulate the result (maybe make it not visible). That's not directly using CSS (though you have to pass a CSS selector to the `lookup` method). I think I would have asked the interviewer why they wanted to do it without CSS, and if they really wanted code written that way I would probably not take the job...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Appreciate it.

Comment: Caveat: "I don't want this job" may have limited practical use, especially if you are early in your career.